# JQuery script not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser, toggleclass

My code is working decently (though slow) in Chrome, but failing in Firefox. Currently the script toggles a class on a list item's hover/click, revealing a div, and a second toggle adds a blur class to the rest of the list items in the navigation. On the second click it closes that div, but does not remove the blur class as it should. I was working on that part when I realized none of the addClass scripts work in Firefox. The div does open/close however so that at least works.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot how to clean this up for Firefox? Also, any thoughts on how to remove the blur-logo class when the list item is clicked again and its' div closed?

Thanks!

I have this mess in the head of my HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/wp-content/themes/etoolkit/js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="sidetogglemenu.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sidetogglemenu.js">
</script>

</head>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-looka"><img src="images/looka-black-circle.png"></a></li>
<li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-sremedy"><img src="images/sremedy-black-circle.png"></a></li>
 <li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-hyperbit"><img src="images/hyperbit-black-circle.png"></a></li>
 </ul>

 <div id="artist-looka" class="artist-box">
 </div>
 <div id="artist-sremedy" class="artist-box">
 </div>
 <div id="artist-hyperbit" class="artist-box">
 </div>
```

Here is my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".artist-box").hide();
        $(".artist-logo").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var clicked = $(this);

            var taggedWithSelect = $('.selected-artist');  

            var clickPartner = $(clicked.attr('href'));
            var selectPartner = $(taggedWithSelect.attr('href'));
            var notClicked = $('.artist-logo').not(clicked);




            if( clicked.hasClass('selected-artist') ) {
                clicked.removeClass('selected-artist');
                unclicked.removeClass('blur-logo');
            } else {

                clicked.addClass('selected-artist');
                taggedWithSelect.removeClass('selected-artist');
                selectPartner.slideToggle();
                notClicked.addClass('blur-logo');
            };
            clickPartner.slideToggle();

        });
 });
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.selected-artist{
    width:100%; 
    max-height: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;  
}

.blur-logo {
    border: 3px red;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px); 
    -moz-filter: blur(3px); 
    -o-filter: blur(3px); 
    -ms-filter: blur(3px); 
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Comment: could the error you are getting? maybe a error trace in the browser?

Comment: what exactly is not working CSS style?

Comment: Please reduce the code down to the minimum that still represents your issue.

Comment: (".artist-box").hide() works fine, but all of the script on "artist-logo" toggling selected-class and also blur-logo don't work in Firefox and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I reduced the code a bit. Hope that helps. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Hey, seems you referenced 2 different versions of jquery - 1.7.2 and 1.8. Not sure, but this may cause some issue. Try again with one jquery reference only.

Answer (score 0):

I've been going over your question for a while and my understanding is that only 2 hrefs can have the 'blur-logo' class when an image is clicked and none when the same image is clicked twice. Given that, I think you should try adding a remove class in the else block (where the code passes on new image click):

```
else {
   clicked.addClass('selected-artist');
   clicked.removeClass('blur-logo');
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This works in removing the blur effect from all list items when the selected is clicked again (to close). Unfortunately, this all still doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: I was actually working on this code on Firefox 28.0, and found no issues in Firebug as well. Maybe try downloading Firebug and see what outputs in the Console?